# Is there an AHk global functions file?

Tags: autohotkey, function-keys

I have installed AHk on my Windows 10 OS and setted it to run on my PC right after boot.

I want to use some "global" AHk functions file that doesn't require the loading of a certain `.ahk` file which I myself created.

Generally, whenever I call a particular function available is in this file (say, by a keyboard combo), it will run.

**Is there an AHk global functions file?**
<sub>I assume that such file would be somewhat parallel to a `~/.bashrc` file.</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mechanisms for global functions:

- [Libraries of Functions: Standard Library and User Library](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs_1.0/Functions.htm#lib)
- The [#Include directive](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs_1.0/commands/_Include.htm)

The libraries are found in the following folders:

```
%A_MyDocuments%\AutoHotkey\Lib\                    ; User library folder
path-to-the-currently-running-AutoHotkey.exe\Lib\  ; Global library folder
```

A library file contains the searched function, having the same file-name as the
function-name.

If you totally want to avoid creating a new `.ahk`, the only solution then would be to modify the source code of AHK to include your functions as built-in;
 Writing a `.ahk` file is much easier;
Note that a *library file* means that your functions are usable in all your scripts without the #Include directive.